# Vertex Colors are changing to white

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

I'm working with THREE.js points and sometimes I need them to have different per point color. Sometimes, I'm also modifying their alpha value so I had to write my own shader programs.

In JavaScript I have the following code:

```
let materials;
if (pointCloudData.colors !== undefined) {
    geometry.colors = pointCloudData.colors.map(hexColor => new THREE.Color(hexColor));
    // If the point cloud has color for each point...
    materials = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
        transparent: true,
    });
} else {
    // Set color for the whole cloud
    materials = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
        uniforms: {
            unicolor: { value: pointCloudData.color },
        },
        vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
        fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
        transparent: true,
    });
}

const pointCloud = new THREE.Points(geometry, materials);
```

I am basically setting the mesh color to a uniform value unless I have defined per point colors - then I set vertexColors to the geometry. I also checked the values being stored in the geometry.colors and they are correct RGB values in range [0,1].

My Vertex Shader code:

```
attribute float size;
attribute float alpha;

varying float vAlpha;
varying vec3 vColor;
void main() {
    vAlpha = alpha;

    #ifdef USE_COLOR
        vColor = color;
    #endif

    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
    gl_PointSize = size * ( 300.0 / -mvPosition.z );
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
}
```

And my Fragment shader code:

```
uniform vec3 unicolor;

varying vec3 vColor;
varying float vAlpha;
void main() {
    #ifdef USE_COLOR
        gl_FragColor = vec4(vColor, vAlpha);
    #else
        gl_FragColor = vec4(unicolor, vAlpha);
    #endif
}
```

Again, I am checking if the vertexColor is set and then passing it to the Fragment Shader which then sets the per point.

For some reason, the vertices are all white when setting the color per point (screenshot: [The white pixels should be green/red](https://i.stack.imgur.com/akTe0.png)). I'm far from advanced user in WebGL and any help would be appreciated. Am I doing something wrong that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a custom `ShaderMaterial` and using this pattern in your fragment shader:

```
#ifdef USE_COLOR
    vColor = color;
#endif
```

Consequently, you need to specify the `material.defines` like so:

```
var defines = {};
defines[ "USE_COLOR" ] = "";

// points material
var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {

    defines:        defines,
    uniforms:       uniforms,
    vertexShader:   document.getElementById( 'vertexshader' ).textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById( 'fragmentshader' ).textContent,
    transparent:    true

} );
```

You do not need to set `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors`. That is just a flag used by built-in materials to alert the renderer to set the `defines` for you.

three.js r.85

Comment: I made the modifications but I got the same results.

The #ifdef code section worked fine even before. It's just that the color is always white. For some reason it's being passed to the Fragment Shader incorrectly.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. The fact that you are setting `geometry.colors` implies you are using `Geometry`, not `BufferGeometry`, in which case this answer is correct. If you are using `BufferGeometry`, then you need to set the attribute, instead. In any event, you are free to provide your own answer for further clarification, but it is best to accept the answer of the person who helped you.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I think I figured it out since it's working now.

I had to set the colors as geometry attributes:

```
const colors = new Float32Array(n * 3);
for (let i = 0; i < n; i += 1) {
    new THREE.Color(pointCloudData.colors[i]).toArray(colors, i * 3);
}
geometry.addAttribute('colors', new THREE.BufferAttribute(colors, 1));
```

I also used the suggestion provided by WestLangley and removed the `vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors,` part from the Material definition and set the define as well:

```
materials = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
    defines: {
        USE_COLOR: '',
    },
    vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertexshader').textContent,
    fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragmentshader').textContent,
    transparent: true,
});
```

Then in my Vertex shader I added:

```
attributes vec3 colors;
```

to get the colors passed from the JavaScript. The rest is the same, I just passed the colors to the fragment shader using the same code as in the posted question above.